# Query to Find and Remove PG Duplicated JSONB Keys and Values

Tags: postgresql, json-value

I would like to be able to Update JSONB column values by removing duplicates, and similarities.

**JSONB VALUES:**

```
    {"Service Types": {"INSURANCE": true, "Insurance": true}}
    {"Service Types": {"HOSPITALS": true, "Hospitals": true}}
    {"Service Types": {"DENTISTS": true, "Dentists": true}}
    {"Service Types": {"Physicians": true, "PHYSICIANS & SURGEONS": true}}
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
    {"Service Types": {"Insurance": true}}
    {"Service Types": {"Hospitals": true}}
    {"Service Types": {"Dentists": true}}
    {"Service Types": {"PHYSICIANS & SURGEONS": true}}
```

EXAMPLE OF DUPLICATES

```
Duplicates: {"INSURANCE": true, "Insurance": true} 
EXPECTED: {"Insurance": true}
```

SIMILARITIES:

```
{"Physicians": true, "PHYSICIANS & SURGEONS": true} 
EXPECTED: {"Physicians": true,} or {"PHYSICIANS & SURGEONS": true}
```

Comment: Sounds like a data mess, and it will be difficult. But you didn't even define what exactly you mean by "duplicate" or "similarity".

Comment: Write function in  PL/pgSQL  or language you know. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html